# Should I call this extension method Remove or RemoveMany?

Tags: c#

I know this is extremely trivial, but would you call the extension method below `Remove` or `RemoveMany`? Please provide justification.

```
public static void Remove<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> set, IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    where TEntity : class
{
    foreach (var entity in entities)
        set.Remove(entity);
}
```

-- or --

```
public static void RemoveMany<TEntity>(...) { ... }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method is removing a collection of entities that exist in some set.

When I see `Remove`, I'd say it removes a single item from something. Now if that collection actually existed in the set, then it would be perfect, but alas it's a collection of items to remove.

One thing to consider, assuming you're making an extension method for the EF5 [`DbSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.103%29), it already has a [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679171%28v=vs.103%29) method that removes a single item, I think an overload to remove more items doesn't sound like a bad idea to me.

On the other hand, LINQ to XML defines a [`Remove()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554) method on enumerables of `XNode`.  But that's an extension on the collection of entities, not the parent set.  I'm a little on the fence on this one.

`RemoveMany`, while better as it indicates we're removing many items, doesn't fit well with me.  It mimics `SelectMany` by name but I'd associate the "Many" part with a projection, certainly not with a remove operation.  I'd avoid that one.

---

I might consider `ExceptEntities` to be similar to the LINQ method [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx).  `Except` returns the set difference of two collections where the result contains unique values.  Since this operation isn't quite the same, we'll still need to make this distinguishable hence the added "Entities".  Since you are dealing with a set (?), this sounds perfect to me.  But after thinking about this more, I'm not quite sure this is the better option since this modifies the collection.

I think `RemoveEntities` might be a better fit.  "Remove" makes it sound as though we're modifying something.  `RemoveAll` doesn't cut it for me as it is named the same as `List.RemoveAll` which removes all that matches a predicate.  There's also a `List.RemoveRange` which removes a range of consecutive values in the collection, not quite the same.

So I'd go with `RemoveEntities` but an overload of the `Remove` name might be fine, just beware of the similarities of the names in other objects.

Comment: +1. I think you managed to get down most of what I was debating in my head, plus a lot more :) Anyway, yes, I'm using the EF DbSet, and the extension method actually *uses* the built-in `Remove()` method inside the loop. As for `RemoveEntities()`, I see why you suggest this, but to me, it would only make sense if the native method were called `RemoveEntity()`. So, at the moment, I'm leaning toward just `Remove()` for the extension method.

Answer (score 4):

I'd consider calling it `RemoveAll`.

Comment: Interesting idea, but one possible problem with `RemoveAll()` is that it might imply that you are clearing out all the entities in the set. What this extension method is supposed to do is clear out only the entities that are passed into the `entities` parameter.

Comment: @DanM I think this can be remedied by introducing an overload without the `entities` parameter, which would fit in well with the LINQ `Any()` and `Any(x => x.Age > 18)` overload scheme.

Answer (score 3):

Just one correction. You cant modify the enumeration inside the for each. Try

```
    public static void RemoveMany<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> thisDbSet, IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class
    {
        for (int i = entities.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (entities.ElementAt(i) != null)
                thisDbSet.Remove(entities.ElementAt(i));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `RemoveExisting` considering you are removing existing entities from the object.

Comment: I'm removing only a *subset* of the existing entities, so I think this would be misleading.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought you were removing all entities that were supplied in the parameter where they existed in the DbSet.

Comment: Wait, I actually *am* removing all entities supplied in the parameter, but I'm not removing all "existing" entities in the set. Wouldn't the method name would normally refer to the object being acted on (the DbSet) and not the parameter (the collection of entities)?

Comment: yep, good point.

Comment: If you're removing a subset, why not `RemoveSubset`?